# Does a for loop in R, unlists the temp variable before making a comaprison?

Tags: r

My list logs is a list of list with the below structure,

```
$ :List of 3
  ..$ success  : logical TRUE
  ..$ details  :List of 1
  .. ..$ message: chr "check"
  ..$ timestamp: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-09-14 23:01:07"
```

Now when i loop over the list to find cases where success==FALSE, and then append this to the "Failure" list.

the way i do this is by,

```
failures <- list()
for (log in logs) {
  if (log$success==FALSE) {

    failures <- c(failures, log)
  }
}
```

This way i get a list of different data types instead of getting a list of lists. However, when i use the function list over my temp variable log while appending I get a list of lists.

```
 failures <- list()
for (log in logs) {
  if (log$success==FALSE) {

    failures <- c(failures, list(log))
  }
}
```

So I wanted to know if R does an unlist while looping over a list of list ?

Comment: Try  `logs[!vapply(logs,function(x) x$success,TRUE)]`.

Comment: Please put the result of `dput(logs)` in your question!

Answer (score 0):

failures = Filter(Negate(is.null),lapply(logs, function(x){if(!x$success) return(x)}))